# grep -v '.*' not working

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, readline

This entirely useless command excludes everything piped to grep, as expected:

```
$ man man | grep -v '.*'
$
```

How am I getting output from piping `bind -p` to this?

```
$ bind -p | grep -v '.*'
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
(227 more...)
```

The exit code is 0 and there is nothing written to stderr.

Comment: try `bind -p 2>/dev/null | grep -v '.*'`. Good luck.

Comment: To explain @shellter's answer, the pipe takes the standard output and pipes it into the next command. But it does not do anything with the standard error, so you'll see anything there displayed. The 2> will redirect standard error to a file, in this case /dev/null (i.e. throw it away)

Comment: Good thought, but not the issue. The exit code is 0 and there is nothing written to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine, your `"?"` is actually `"�"`. That's the UNICODE character used as a fallback when decoding fails.

It looks like `bind -p` outputs invalid UTF-8 sequences, and `grep -v '.*'` does not filter them because it cannot decode them in the first place.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Any ideas how to filter as desired?

Comment: @Raine, I don't think the usual utilities can be coerced into processing invalid input (which those UTF-8 sequences are), because that would be quite dangerous: you cannot rely on data you could not decode properly. I also didn't find a way to put them in "binary mode". At this stage, I would recommend writing a script in Python, Perl, or anything of that kind you may have at hand.

Comment: @Raine Try with `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: @tripleee, tried it, didn't work, at least from `bash` itself.